# Adding spaces between characters inside a string

Tags: python, string

This is a Kata challenge. The function should return a string with spaces between each character. So "Hi there" should equal the the string with spaces between each letter, two spaces between the words. My code actually works in my Python environment, but it is not accepted on Kata.

```
def spacing(string):
    return " ".join(a for a in string).split(string)
```

Comment: Try removing that split ,maybe they are expecting only string.

Comment: You say "the function should return a string" but `.split()` function does not return a string but an array

Comment: Your solution returns a list `['H i   t h e r e']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string when iterated over is considered a sequence of characters, so you can simply pass the string to the `join` method directly:

```
def spacing(string):
    return ' '.join(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
def spacing(string):
   return " ".join(string.replace(" ", ""))
```

this will work if the only whitespaces in string are spaces.